# C++ / Указатель(pointer) / передача в функцию (pass to function) forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

//Преобразование "строки" в "СТРОКУ"

```
void fFirstF(string ***fSent){
    int nLen = 10; //Потому что nLen = ***fSent.length() не работает
    for(int i = 0; i < nLen; i++){
        if ( ***(fSent + i) >= 'a' && (fSent[i]** <= 'z')){    // ***(fSent + i) ошибка тут
            ***(fSent + i) -= 32;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кхм, а что это за бред? `*****(fSent + i)**`

Comment: Начнем с того, что в `if` количество открывающих скобок не равно количеству закрывающих, так что... во-вторых, ну как вы планируете разыменовывать `bool`? Что за `\*\*` *справа*? Словом, это какой-то бред, а не код. И вообще, не представляю ситуации, где требуется третий уровень косвенности. Это не отель - столько звездочек лепить...

Comment: думаю звездочки просто потому что была попытка выделить полужирным. И если аккуратно по 2+2 звездочки поубирать, то все стает на свои места.

Answer (score 2):

По факту, string  (если это std::string) это класс, а не голый указатель/массив и к нему нельзя применять адресную арифметику. Для обычных массивов `a[b] == *(a+b)`, а для классов, у которых определен `operator[]` такое не работает. Собственно об этом компилятор и говорит. Что делать? либо писать так, как того хочет язык с++ (fSent[i]) либо переходить на си или те языки, которые соответствуют Вашим желаниям.

```
void fFirstF(string& fSent){
    int nLen = fSent.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < nLen; i++){
        if ( fSent[i] >= 'a' && fSent[i] >= 'a'){
           fSent[i] += 22;
        }
    }
}
```

и сразу видно, что что то пошло не так - условие дублируется.

Посмотрел в код, поправил его максимально сохраняя стиль

```
void fMain(string *fSent);
void fFirstF(string* fSent) {
    int nLen = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i < nLen; i++){
        if ( (*fSent)[i] >= 'a' && (*fSent)[i] <= 'z'){
             (*fSent)[i] += 22;
        }
    }
}

void fIsQuit(char chIsQuit, string *fSent)
{
    switch (chIsQuit)
    {
        case '1':{
            fFirstF(fSent);
            fMain(fSent);
            break;
        } 
        case 'f':{ return; } 
    }
} 

void fMain(string *fSent) {
    char chAnsw = ' ';
    cin >> chAnsw;
    fIsQuit(chAnsw, fSent);
}

int main()
{
    string sSent = "";
    getline(cin, sSent);
    fMain(&sSent);
}
```

теперь оно как минимум компилится. Также поправил знак возле 'z'. И понял, почему возникло сколько звездочек - при каждой передаче параметра в новую функцию, почему то появляется амерсанд... не нужно так.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, только ошибка все та же, я вчера как только ни пробовал и (int***)(fSent + i) >= 'a' , и ***(fSent + i) >= 'a' , и fSent[i] >= 'a' - все такая же ошибка, ошибка сравнения указателя и типа данных integer. Гуглил ошибку.. везде сказано про ошибку записи "a" , но у меня изначально было 'a' .. не понимаю, в чем дело.

Comment: @ArtyomKaplich Точно в этой функции? Минимальный компилируемый пример был бы полезен.

Comment: немного не понял Васб о каком примере идет речь?

Comment: просто покажите код, который Вы пытаетесь скомпилировать

Comment: void fMain(string *fSent);
void fFirstF(string ***fSent){
int nLen = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < nLen; i++){
if ( fSent[i] >= 'a' && (fSent[i]) >= 'z'){
***(fSent + i) += 22;}}}

void fIsQuit(char chIsQuit, string **fSent){
switch (chIsQuit) {
case '1':{
fFirstF(&fSent);
fMain(*fSent);
break;}
case 'f':{
return;}}}

void fMain(string *fSent){
char chAnsw = ' ';

cin >> chAnsw;
fIsQuit(chAnsw, &fSent);}
int main(){
string sSent = "";
cout << "Enter your sentence please: ";
getline(cin, sSent);
fMain(&sSent);
}

Comment: не понимаю, как оформить в виде кода, потому что это нечитаемо.. прошу прощения

Comment: в коде выше я убрал лишние case, а то лимит в кол-во символов. И я хочу именно через указатели это бахнуть, без return типа string.

Программа должна выполнять преобразования строки (длина строки 255 символов): СТРОКА ЗАГЛАВНЫМИ БУКВАМИ, строка в нижнем регистре, С Заглавной Буквы, пЕРВЫЙ сИМВОЛ в нИЖНЕМ рЕГИСТРЕ, Как в предложении(с заглавной буквы)., Символ 'f' — выход из программы

Comment: Получается все было из-за большого количества звездочек..? я только знакомлюсь с указателями и из-за нехватки информации натворил такого. Плюс вроде бы сделал несколько задач с массивами одно- / дву- мерными с помощью указателей, а тут вот такое.

Comment: &  берет указатель у переменной. А что там за переменная, ему побоку, хоть указатель на указатель. А потом разыменовываете, но некрасиво. Плюс добавили сишного синтаксиса для строки

Comment: так я ведь и учу c++, или синтаксис для строки на с++ не так выглядит?

Comment: в плюсах есть полноценная строка и она хоть и выглядит как массив, и внутри есть массив, но арифметику указателей не поддерживает.

Comment: я лишь слышал про библиотеку string и представление строки в виде массива из char'ов, но для меня практичнее почему-то string библиотека.

Во всяком случае, спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: библиотека string - это мощно. Это часть стандартной библиотеки.